# The Clean Up Badge

Tags: social-sound-design

I just took a look at the badges and most of them seem pretty straight forward. But what the heck is a rollback and how does one do that?

@Benjie @Cvrgoje @Modraw & @Utopia - y'all are the only users that have this badge - any clues?

Comment: Um, did an answer regarding public humiliation and mud appear here briefly? I'm looking at you @Utopia…

Comment: Yeah - it's so embarrassing I can't repeat it.

Comment: @Utopia, dude I'd have picked that up as the official answer. Why did you delete?

Comment: …and rollback badged.

Comment: @georgi.m @AdamAxbey K - I rolled it back. T'was a joke and I was waiting for someone to undelete it, but, fine. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WTF.

At my first SSD meet-up party Andrew, Shaun, Jay and Colin made me douse myself with mud and roll in a swine pit backwards in order to award me with the "rollback" badge.

I guess it was some kind of SSD hazing prank. Yeah, pick on the new guy why dontcha.

Bah!

:)

p.s. Rene recorded it and put it up on his blog as a free download. :(

Answer (score 2):

a site like this allows anyone to edit anything (including other people's posts), whilst keeping versions of the content, so a rollback is just that - rolling back to a previous edit.

p.s.: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56287/how-can-i-get-the-cleanup-badge

Comment: Thanks @georgi.m! I did google rollback and badge, but I had no idea this site was create by the Stack Overflow (or what Stack Overflow was) so my google was all "gruh?" when I queried with "rollback badge"
